# Unable to upgrade usrmerge due to both /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 exist

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg

I am trying to update my ubuntu packages using
`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` and I got the following message.

```
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.

FATAL ERROR:
Both /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 and /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 exist.

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up libllvm13:amd64 (1:13.0.1-2ubuntu2.1) ...
Setting up open-vm-tools (2:11.3.5-1ubuntu4.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
Setting up libxslt1.1:amd64 (1.1.34-4ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-common (4.4.1-2.3ubuntu2.2) ...
Setting up ubuntu-advantage-tools (27.10.1~22.04.1) ...
Setting up software-properties-common (0.99.22.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL2:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

What should I do to fix this problem?

I tried to remove one of `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`, but that doesn't seem to solve this problem.

Many thanks in advance.

Update:

Neither seems to be a symlink file (checking with `ls -l`). The `realpath` direct each file to themselves, not the same file. `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` gives `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` and `dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` gives `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`

Comment: Are you able to identify the origins of the two libraries (ex. `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`)? Are they both symlinks? Do they both resolve to the same file (ex. `realpath /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`)?

Comment: Neither seems to be a symlink file (when I try ```cat``` both files appear to be binary). The realpath direct each file to themselves, not the same file. ```dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6``` gives ```dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6``` and ```dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6``` gives ```dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6```

Comment: Please [edit] this information into your question - as well, `cat` doesn't tell you whether they are symlinks, please use `ls -l` and/or `realpath`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue on debian (a badly failed upgrade, luckily it was a vm and I was able to mount the drives on another VM and recover)

From what I can tell the package is moving from one place to the other and then putting in symlinks and then replacing them with synlinks.  I removed one and replaced it with a symlink to the other then re-ran `/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge`, rince and repeat until all errors were gone.
When the system was back I ran `dpkg -S` on each and the results were

```
# dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
libc6:amd64: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6

# dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

I hope this  helps and as ever YMMV

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think my ubuntu fixed itself somehow (I don't exactly know how) recently in some upgrade so I can't test your solution out, but do keep it here in case it helped someone else out!